# 「深酷」とは　どういう意味ですか

Tags: meaning, kyūjitai-and-shinjitai, connotation

現在、私は戦前の日本語を読んでいるところで、辞書にも存在していないことばを見つけました。次の文です：

> ...極めて深酷に徹底的と云はざるを得ない。

推測ですが、私にはこのように思われます：

> ...極めて深刻に徹底的と言えざるを得ない。

かと思っていますが、辞書などの根拠がないので、ちょっと自信がないです。

[旧字体・新字体の便利帳](http://www.benricho.org/moji_conv/14_shin_kyu_kanji.html)を見ても、これは書いてありません。

質問として、

1. 私の推測があっているかどうかをチェックしてもらいたいです。
2. またできれば、どこか辞典で掲載しているところを教えてください。
3. この「深酷」と普通の「深刻」で意味の違うところがあれば、教えてほしいです。

---

Presently, I am reading some pre-war Japanese, and I ran across a word that does not exist in the dictionary. The sentences is as follows:

> ...極めて深酷に徹底的と云はざるを得ない。

As a guess, I think that this means the following:

> ....極めて深刻に徹底的と言えざるを得ない。

i.e. we must state that which is absolutely and thoroughly foundational.

My question is three-fold:

1. First, I want someone to check if my supposition is correct.
2. Is there any where that this is written in a dictionary?
3. I would like to learn if this 深酷 differ at all from the common 深刻 in meaning.

Comment: 一応辞書には載せてありますが: 学研漢和大字典「 【深酷】（シンコク) ⇒深刻」、漢字源「深刻 ① 態度や刑罰が非常にきびしくむごたらしいこと。『深酷』」

Comment: @blutorange viele Danke fuer sein Antwoertekomment! Kann ich dass auf dem Internet lesen oder mussen ich kaufen es?

Comment: Bitte sehr. Die Wörterbücher habe ich in digitaler Form gekauft. Ich habe mal geschaut, aber es scheint keine kostenlose Onlineversion zu geben. Zumindestens vom *Kanjigen* scheint es aber eine Version für Android zu geben.(22€). Vieles findet man heute im Netz, aber eben noch nicht alles. (Ist das nun gut oder schlecht?)

Comment: das ist wirklich interessant.

Comment: @blutorange [Comments are not for answers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/593/comments-are-not-for-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**学研漢和大字典**](http://hon.gakken.jp/book/1230008200)

> 【深酷】（シンコク) ⇒深刻

---

[**漢字源**](http://hon.gakken.jp/book/1230310100)

> 【深刻】
>
> ① **〔『深酷』とも〕態度や刑罰が非常にきびしくむごたらしいこと。**
>
> ② ふかくほりきざむ。
>
> ③〔国〕情勢などが切実でいたましい。
>
> ④〔国〕情勢が切実で重大である。

---

So as the *kanji* implies, 深酷 is an alternative spelling with a nuance of a grave or harsh or atrocious (酷い【ひどい】, 酷い【むごい】) situation.

---

Perhaps it is worth noting that the Agency of Cultural Affairs considers 深刻 more common:

> **文化庁**
>
> **語形の「ゆれ」の問題　漢字表記の「ゆれ」について**
>
> [...]
>
> 次に挙げる語なども，かっこの外のほうが一般的であると考えられる。
>
> 栄　養（営　養）  　　簡　単（簡　短）
>
> 観　点（看　点）  　　気　概（気　慨）
>
> 機　転（気　転）  　　規　範（軌　範）
>
> 漁　網（魚　網）  　　幸　運（好　運）
>
> 豪　胆（剛　胆）  　　作　戦（策　戦）
>
> 残　酷（残　刻）  　　自　動（自　働）
>
> 集　荷（集　貨）  　　冗　員（剰　員）
>
> 定　規（定　木）  　　定　宿（常　宿）
>
> 常　連（定　連）  　　準決勝（准決勝）
>
> 親　切（深　切）  　　**深　刻（深　酷）**
>
> 素　性（素　姓）  　　整　然（井　然）
>
> 折　衷（折　中）  　　先　頭（先　登）
>
> 奏　功（奏　効）  　　滞　貨（滞　荷）
>
> 端　正（端　整）  　　富　裕（富　有）

([kokugo.bunka.go.jp](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kakuki/05/bukai02/04.html))